# change asp net mvc controller name in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

If we have "example_name" we can change it in url using [ActionName("")] So, i want to do this for controller name.

I can do this:

ControllerName > example_nameController > in URL: "/case_studies/adaep"

I would like to change controller name like this in URL: "/case-studies/adaep"

```
 [RoutePrefix("case-studies")]
public class case_studiesController : Controller
{
    // GET: CaseStudies
    [Route]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("adaep")]
    public ActionResult adaep()
    {
        return View("/views/case-studies/pagename.cshtml");
    }
}
```

i do it like this but not working still controller name with `/example_controller`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the routes globally:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
// routes.MapRoute...
}
```

create a custom route handler as shown in this blog:

```
public class MyRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler{
    protected override IHttpHandler  GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

...and the new route:

```
routes.Add(
        new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = "" }),
                new MyRouteHandler())
    );
```